# Замена строки в функции

Tags: javascript, функции, dom

У меня есть функция, которую я хочу применить ещё раз в другом месте, но у неё будет отличие всего-лишь в одной строке. Можно ли как-то заменить эту строку, не копируя всю функцию? Строку `input.setAttribute('value', li[i]);` хочу заменить на `input.setAttribute('value', document.getElementById("new_meaning").value);`

```
function replaceElem() {
            let sistersLi = ol.childNodes;
            console.log(sistersLi);
            for (let i = 0; i < sistersLi.length; i++) {
                let sisters_Li = sistersLi[i];
                sisters_Li.style.cssText = 'cursor:pointer;width:500px';
                let input = document.createElement('input');
                input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                input.setAttribute('class', 'strange');
                input.setAttribute('value', li[i]);
                sisters_Li.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                    //evt.currentTarget - li, находим все спаны
                    let span = evt.currentTarget.querySelector('span');
                    if (span) {
                        //если спан найден, то делаем замену
                        evt.currentTarget.replaceChild(input, span);
                        //при отсутствии blur
                        input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
                            let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
                            newSpan.innerHTML = input.value;
                            sisters_Li.replaceChild(newSpan, input);
                        });
                    }
                    input.focus();
                });

            }
        }
        replaceElem();
```

Comment: В этой функции у вас динамический `value` для элементов списка. А вы хотите сделать, чтобы он был постоянно один и тот же.

Comment: Кстати, откуда она вообще берется эта `li[i]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого есть параметры функции) Но т.к. у вас `li[i]`, а он в момент вызова функции еще не определен, можно задать её в виде строки, в 'кавычках'. А потом использовать `eval()` - он берет любую строку и выполняет как код. Поэтому вместо `eval('li[i]')` в этом месте кода появится просто `li[i]`

```
replaceElem('li[i]');
replaceElem('document.getElementById("new_meaning").value');

function replaceElem(bubu) {
  let sistersLi = ol.childNodes;
  console.log(sistersLi);
  for (let i = 0; i < sistersLi.length; i++) {
    let sisters_Li = sistersLi[i];
    sisters_Li.style.cssText = 'cursor:pointer;width:500px';
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('class', 'strange');
    input.setAttribute('value', eval(bubu) ); /* <---  */
    console.log(bubu);

    sisters_Li.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
      let span = evt.currentTarget.querySelector('span');
      if (span) {
        evt.currentTarget.replaceChild(input, span);
        input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
          let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
          newSpan.innerHTML = input.value;
          sisters_Li.replaceChild(newSpan, input);
        });
      }
      input.focus();
    });
  }
}
```

Но eval не рекомендуется использовать, если строка-код может быть получен от пользователя. Мало ли что могут подсунуть...